# how to modify win keyboard shortcut?

Tags: windows, autohotkey

I set the windows taskbar to autohide. So I want a keyboard shortcut can quickly show it.
The "Win+T" can do it, but is to hard to press it.

So, I want to modify "Win+T" to "Win+A". I think AutoHotKey can do it but i don't know how to write the script.

Here is what I want to do:
1. When taskbar is hidden,"Win+A" can show it.
2. When taskbar is showing,"Win+A" can hide it.

How can I do it?

Thanks!

Comment: You can figure this out by a simple read of the documentation: http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried the following?

```
#a::Send, #t
```